# Does an EU citizen need a visa to visit Australia for holidays?

Tags: visas, australia, eu-citizens

Is a visa required, or is just a passport enough, for a short holiday trip to Australia?

Specifically, how is it for citizens of Nordic EU member countries such as Finland?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

**Yes**, a visa is required for EU citizens.

Fortunately, getting one is free and (usually) pretty quick. 
The easiest way is to [apply for **eVisitor** online](https://www.homeaffairs.gov.au/Trav/Visi/Visi/Visitor-visas/eVisitor-online-application). See "Eligible passport holders" on that page to check if you are eligible for eVisitor.

> The eVisitor allows visitors to travel to Australia for short term
>   business or tourism purposes for up to three months. eVisitor
>   applications are free and are available to passport holders from the
>   European Union and a number of other European countries.

More information on Australian visas can be found at https://www.homeaffairs.gov.au/trav/visi

Comment: Personally this surprised me last spring (as pampered EU/Nordic tourists rarely need a visa and I assumed a passport would suffice). I'm glad someone happened to ask me about it while I still had a week or two in my previous destination before flight to Australia.

Comment: If you are going to some of the small island such as Norfolk Island  you should do some reading as they come under different rules. http://wikitravel.org/en/Norfolk_Island#Get_in

Comment: Interestingly, Australia changed the name of the thing to pretend it's not a visa but a mere electronic authorization like the US ESTA for the sake of reciprocity. It is easier to get than a regular visa but refusal rates for some EU countries like Romania and Bulgaria are close to 20%, which is why they consider it to be a visa and asked the EU Commission to take action.

Comment: The eVisitor is as much of a visa as the ESTA, but eh!

Comment: First link is broken

Answer (score 7):

Many visitors to Australia like to stay longer than the 90 days you get on the free eVisitor visa.

In that case you need an Tourist Visa (Subclass 676), which allows you to stay six or even twelve months. This visa is not free, more information can be found at 
[www.immi.gov.au/visitors/tourist/676/](http://www.immi.gov.au/visitors/tourist/676/)

Please note that after applying for a visa you need to use it within a year. I never made it to Australia in the first 12 months of my trip and had to buy another visa when I finally got there.

Answer (score 5):

Actually... ALL citizens, except New Zealand citizens need a visa to enter Australia. As other people have suggested above, only European and a few other countries can apply online, which is quick. Visitors from most other countries are ineligible to do it online and must wait days for a paper based application process to be complete.

So, although you need a visa, it is a quick, online one... and issued free of charge :)

Comment: Wouldn't an American passport work for up to 90 days?

Comment: @Panzercrisis, [US citizens also need a visa](http://usa.embassy.gov.au/whwh/visiting_australia.html) (like everyone else, except New Zealand citizens)