# Do I need a US visa to transit (or layover) through an American airport?

Tags: visas, usa, air-travel, transit, transit-visas

In Europe usually you don't need to go through immigration to change planes (unless you are entering/exiting Schengen). Is it the case in the US as well? May I catch a connecting flight on one of the US airports if I don't have US visa?

Comment: Shorter version: **Yes**, you need either a visa or visa waiver (ESTA). Getting the latter can actually take *more* trouble/money than a proper visa to [some other countries](http://travel.stackexchange.com/a/1931/583) (so it's not much of a "waiver"). And **yes**, you need it [even if you merely change planes in the US](http://travel.stackexchange.com/a/2983/583). Yes, this sucks.

Answer (score 90, accepted):

Unlike many other countries, US airports do not have any form of physical immigration controls when you are departing the country on an international flight. In fact, in most airports there isn't even a concept of an "International" terminal/gate, with the same gates frequently being used for international flights and domestic flights.

As a result of this they can't enforce the concept of a 'transit' passenger - once you're in the departure area, even if you got there on the pretext of catching another international flight out of the country a few hours later, there's nothing to stop you boarding a different domestic flight, or even simply walking out of the airport!

This means that ALL passengers arriving on international flights in the US must have the legal right to enter the US; i.e, you must either be a US citizen/green card holder, be from a country that does not have any visa requirements (such as Canada or Bermuda), be from a country that is a part of the US Visa Waiver Program and have a valid [ESTA](https://esta.cbp.dhs.gov/), or have a US Visa.

If you require a Visa then there is a ["Transit Visa" (C)](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/us-visas/other-visa-categories/transit.html) available which is normally a little easier to obtain than a normal visa, but you'll still need to go through the full visa application process, including showing proof that you intend to leave the US (almost) immediately.

Comment: I'll second this.  I actually have walked out from the international departure gate to an area outside--the plane was very late and I wanted food other than what was available in the terminal.  There was no check of any kind on the way out and coming back there was nothing but the normal security you would find in any airport.

Comment: +1 I flew into the USA from Fiji, landed in LA with New York as my final destination.  But I had to go through immigration control in LA, collect my checked-in luggage and check in again to board my flight to NY.

Comment: I'm slightly confused. How to they perform immigration control in these cases i.e how do they "know" if I have a visa or not? Is this only the case for transit flights or is this the case for arrivals as well?

Comment: @AdityaSomani All arrivals in the US must go through immigration, regardless of whether you are transiting or arriving.  There is no way to get to a departing flight from the area where incoming flights arrive except via immigration.

Comment: @Doc Ahh I understand now. So basically once you leave the arrival after the immigration you MUST have a transit VISA or any other similar document because the departure lounge is unprotected and you can walk out at ease right? I remember what Loren is talking about in a previous comment quite vividly from one of my own experiences in Atlanta as well.

Comment: Simple explanation as to why U.S. airports are designed this way: they got there first and now they're the worst.

Answer (score 18):

First of all it depends what nationality you are. I assume you are from a country that is part of the US visa waiver program. In this case you don't need a visa but you do need a travel authorization (ESTA) even if you are only changing planes in the US without leaving the airport.

Source: [ESTA-FAQ](https://esta.cbp.dhs.gov/esta/WebHelp/ESTA_Screen-Level_Online_Help_1.htm#TA8) of the Department of Homeland Security.

So there is no difference between visiting the US for 90 days or just transiting, in both cases you need an ESTA. It currently costs $14 and you can do it online before leaving for the US.

Comment: The accepted answer on [this question](http://travel.stackexchange.com/q/2970/108) may also be of interest.

Comment: Sadly I am not from a country that is part of the US visa waiver program. So you are saying that unlike in Europe, changing to a connecting flight requires passing through US immigration?

Comment: Yes it does, when you arrive by any plane in the US, you always have to go through US immigration, even if you are just on transit to another country. If you can't do ESTA, you may need a proper visa. Please change your question to include your nationality.

Comment: ESTA is a visa, never mind what DHS says about it. The only difference is the application process and the price.

Comment: I agree with @jwenting 100%. Australians also have a similar procedure to apply for a visa on the Internet, they just use the proper name for it.

Comment: and it's little different from places like Turkey or Indonesia where you have to buy what's essentially an entrance fee on passing through customs, which grants you a visa as well.

Comment: Technically the ESTA is NOT a Visa. It's an automated check for people from people counties to determine if they will be admitted without a visa.  Whilst this might sound like semantics, there's one significant difference - if you are denied a Visa then you basically have zero recourse, you will not be allowed into the US, and have to declare the fact that your visa application was rejected on all future attempts to obtain a US visa.  If you are denied an ESTA then it means that you have to go through the usual Visa application process, but you are not (automatically) denied entry to the US.

Comment: @jwenting What's a visa beyond what local law defines as a visa?

Comment: @Annoyed traditionally it's a travel permit applied for in advance, presumably granted only after the person has been investigated for anything that would be problematic for denying entry. I agree that over time in many countries it's been watered down to little more than a formality and a means to make some hard currency income from foreigners, the on-arrivals things like Indonesia and Turkey have are the ultimate in those, effectively turning the visa process into little more than a ticket booth at an amusement park. Wonder how the local population would react to it being called that.

Comment: @jwenting You did not understand the “question”, really. My point is that a visa is nothing else than what the local law says it is, period. Historically speaking, all this (citizenship, making entry difficult, etc.) is quite new anyway and I don't see why people should mind that their government is welcoming tourists and trying to make some money in the process.

Comment: @Relaxed I was just re-reading this question/answer/comments and.... the problem is people don't mind that *their* government is welcoming tourists and trying to make money... people mind that all of the *other* countries are .....

Comment: Visa at arrival means you are not eligible for some customs exemptions, though. They can turn you over for anything. It is very different from e-visa. Always choose e-visa if you have choice between prior e-visa and visa at arrival.