# Will I need a transit visa for US as a Canadian Student Visa holder?

Tags: usa, visas, pakistani-citizens

I have a Canadian student Visa, and Pakistani by nationality. I wish to travel from Canada to Pakistan with a 7 hours transit in US. Do I need a transit Visa?

Comment: See if [this question](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/4859/do-i-need-a-us-visa-to-change-planes-in-an-american-airport) helps you. If it does, then we'll close this one as a duplicate.

Comment: @Omar: The answer is: yes, regardless of status in another country, you need a transit visa or fall under a Visa Waiver Program (which you don't).

Comment: @mindcorrosive: We could add to the linked accepted answer "this is true even if you have a Canadian visa".