# Transiting from Heathrow (LHR) to Newark (EWR) to La Guardia (LGA) to Toronto Pearson International Airport (YYZ)

Tags: transit, ewr, lga

I have a valid Canadian Study Permit - Visa and will be travelling to Toronto Canada this summer via British Airways and I've booked and paid for my flight ticket, which has 2 connections from Muritala Muhammad Airport in Lagos to Heathrow Airport London and to Newark Liberty International (EWR) to LaGuardia Airport (LGA) in order to board my final flight to Toronto. My question goes thus: do I need a Transit Visa to board the US bound plane from Heathrow to Newark International and transiting from Newark Liberty International to LaGuardia Airport to board my last flights to Toronto?

Comment: assume if you're from Lagos that you're a Nigerian citizen?

Comment: Newark and LaGuardia are about a 30 min taxi ride from each other. You will be loose in the USA as far as immigration is concerned.

Comment: See also: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/4859/do-i-need-a-us-visa-to-change-planes-in-an-american-airport

Comment: @mindcorrosive hmm, I'd be inclined to say then that this is a duplicate...?

Comment: @KateGregory Newark to LaGuardia is a lot more than 30 minutes apart at any time other than the absolute dead of night. And even then, we're still probably talking an hour with no traffic. It's 25 miles, but you won't get over 30-40 MPH for most of that distance.

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz that just makes it even more so that going between these two airports is not at all like transiting within a single airport. And anyway the US doesn't really "get" transiting within a single airport.

Answer (score 1):

You will need a visa for the US.  Transit as a concept does not exist in US Airports, and as a result, everyone either needs US Citizenship, an ESTA (Visa Waiver) if part of the [list of countries eligible for the Visa Waiver Program in the Unites States](http://travel.state.gov/visa/temp/without/without_1990.html).

Seeing as you're from Lagos (Nigerian citizen I assume?), you aren't eligible for the VWP, and as such require a [Class C Visa for transiting in the US to get to Canada](http://travel.state.gov/visa/temp/types/types_1286.html).