# Will I need a US visa

Tags: visas, usa, transit

Flying from Heathrow on United Airlines, changing planes at Newark then taking another United Airlines flight to Costa Rica.  Do I still need a US visa.  Also, returning via Toronto, will I need a visa for Canada.  I am British.

Comment: Nationality? so we can answer....

Answer (score 1):

As per the answer to [Do I need a US visa to transit (or layover) through an American airport?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/4859/do-i-need-a-us-visa-to-change-planes-in-an-american-airport) you will require an ESTA (similar to a visa, but obtained electronically) before travelling the US, even though you are only transiting through the US. ESTAs are relatively easy to obtain (presuming you do not have a criminal record/etc), and cost only $14 per person.

UK citizens do NOT require a Visa or anything similar to transit Canada.