# French student in Canada: going back home from NYC

Tags: usa, canada, esta, french-citizens

I'm French, and I will continue my studies in Montreal during the next 3 years.

Next year, I will go back to France for holidays, and I would like to take my flight from NYC. What are the formalities?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Do I need a US visa to change planes in an American airport?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/4859/do-i-need-a-us-visa-to-change-planes-in-an-american-airport)

Comment: @Karlson How does it work if you are traveling overland?

Comment: @Annoyed In the exact same manner unless you hold a Canadian citizenship

Comment: @Karlson I thought ESTA was only for air or sea travel?

Comment: @Annoyed In order to enter US you need a visa or an ESTA for Visa Waiver which is exactly what the answer states.  But irrespective of that crossing the border by land in New York City is not a possibility so you either cross the border elsewhere in the state of New York and have to travel through it or you cross in the port or the airport in which case ESTA applies.

Comment: @Karlson Maybe, that's possible, I don't know what gave me this impression. It would seem to be a answer to this question, then. (The other question is about air transit and the answer does not actually state anything one way or the other about entering from Canada by land).

Comment: @Karlson Well, who said anything about crossing the border by land *in* NYC? It's the plane that Adrien would catch there, reaching the city by another means. He could confirm or infirm that but that's how I understood the phrase “take my flight *from* NYC”…

Comment: @Annoyed My understanding is the same.  Personally I wouldn't want to spend 8 hours on the bus to get to New York and then another hour getting to JFK but rather spend the same time on the plane for about the same amount of money.

Comment: Actually, I would like to reach the city by bus and then visiting it during few days before taking my flight to Paris.

Comment: @Karlson Reaching New York by bus from Montreal is a lot cheaper than plane, don't you think ?

Comment: @Karlson you probably never experienced the airport fees of Canada. It saves a lot of money to fly from Buffalo/Burlington/Seattle in the US close to the border than from a Canadian airport. As for the question, the FAQ of ESTA website states : "All passengers traveling under the Visa Waiver Program are required to have an approved travel authorization prior to traveling to the United States by air or sea." I don't know if things change in the last 3 years, but back then entering the US by bus/car did NOT require an ESTA. You just paid 6 dollars by cash or credit card and got an I94.

Comment: Just to clarify, ESTA only works by land if within 90 days of a flight.  I found this out the hard way.  It's still easy enough, I got a visa on arrival at the US border near Vancouver, but there was a brief moment of concern.

Comment: @AdrienBudet Depends if 8+ hours on the bus is worth it for you.  But that doesn't change the crux of the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are a citizen of a Visa Waiver Program country (France).

(Here's [a list of Visa Waiver Program countries](https://esta.cbp.dhs.gov/esta/WebHelp/ESTA_Screen-Level_Online_Help_1.htm#vwp2))

Therefore:

- If you plan to travel overland from Canada to US (bus, train, or car) you do not need to do anything in advance. At the border you will fill out an I-94W form. [Source](https://help.cbp.gov/app/answers/detail/a_id/1132/~/citizen-of-visa-waiver-country,-wants-to-drive-into-u.s.-from-canada-or-mexico,)
- If traveling by air, you should get electronic authorization first on the [ESTA website](https://esta.cbp.dhs.gov/esta/) which is required for flying into the US.