# Visa to transit in the US on the way to Canada for Polish citizens?

Tags: visa-free-entry

I am citizen of Poland and I will fly to Canada through US. So, do I need a US visa for my transit journey?

Comment: Poland is not a VWP country, so thus the above answer is correct for you

Answer (score 1):

In the US, being in transit does not exempt you from any potential visa requirement, you need to have the right to enter the country, see [Do I need a US visa to transit (or layover) through an American airport?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/4859/do-i-need-a-us-visa-to-change-planes-in-an-american-airport)

Also, while there have been discussions about participation in the [visa waiver program](http://travel.state.gov/content/visas/english/visit/visa-waiver-program.html) for many years, Poland is still not eligible so that Polish citizens do need a visa to enter the US.