# Travelling to Mexico from the Caribbean through the US without a visa

Tags: visas, air-travel, usa

I'm planning a trip to Cancún, Mexico from The Bahamas without a visa. I'll be traveling by plane with a stop-over in Hartsfield Jackson Atlanta International, USA (ATL) and from there to Cancún.

Do I need a visa to get back in to the US or this won't be a problem?

Comment: Welcome to Travel.SE. You did not indicate your nationality; in any event, there is no sterile international transit via the US. You must have a visa or qualify for a visa waiver.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Do I need a US visa to transit (or layover) through an American airport?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/4859/do-i-need-a-us-visa-to-transit-or-layover-through-an-american-airport)

Answer (score 2):

You will need a visa, assuming you are Bahamian and planning to come back to the Bahamas.

On the out bound flight to Cancun, you can pre-clear US Immigration in Nassau or Freeport and assuming you meet the requirements for Bahamians (no criminal record, traveling for tourism, etc), can enter without a visa for up to 30 days.  But on your return trip from Cancun, you will need a visa to stop-over in Atlanta (or any other USA airport).  If by chance you don't meet the pre-clearance rules, you would need a visa going both ways.

You can find more indepth info on this on the US Embassy website for the Bahamas: http://nassau.usembassy.gov