# Do I need a visa to Transit US?

Tags: visas, air-travel, usa, transit, indian-citizens

I am an Indian travelling from India to Cayman Islands via Dubai and US.  I have a valid Cayman islands work permit. I have a layover in Newyork / Miami for around 5 hrs maximum. Should I need a transit visa to transit US or if I have a dubai visa, is it enough to transit US and reach Cayman islands?

if so what is the best alternative option to reach cayman islands without taking a US visa?

Comment: Regarding US Visa the answer is: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/4859/do-i-need-a-us-visa-to-change-planes-in-an-american-airport

Answer (score 3):

To transit US you will need a Visa see a question that covers that topic:

- [Do I need a US visa to transit (or layover) through an American airport?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/4859/do-i-need-a-us-visa-to-change-planes-in-an-american-airport)

If you're looking for alternatives you may be hard pressed to find them but you could try changing your itinerary to:

Dubai -> Moscow -> Havana -> Grand Cayman

This avoids the US and to the best of the information I have available will not require you to obtain transit visas at your transit points.

Answer (score 2):

There is no such thing as transiting, as it is known in other localities and related to VISA's, within the US. You must go through US Customs and Border Protection, or its representatives, any time you deplane in the US. So, if you stick with your flight plan, to include the layovers in NYC/Miami, yes, you would need a VISA. (India is not currently in the VISA Waiver Program, so that is also not an option.)