# Do I need a transit visa going through the US?

Tags: visas, usa, transit, iranian-citizens

I am an Iranian citizen travelling from Canada to Iran. I'm holding a Canadian work permit.

Do I need a transit visa if my flight goes through the US?

Comment: Yes, and it costs the same as a tourist visa and requires approximately all the same paperwork. You can get one, but it will be much less hassle to change your flight to avoid the US.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. The US does not have airside transit, you will need a C-1 transit visa or B-2 visitor visa.

Comment: Do you have a link or source to back this up? It's been auto-flagged as a low quality answer for basically being just a dozen or so words :/

Comment: http://travel.state.gov/content/visas/english/other/transit.html http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/4859/do-i-need-a-us-visa-to-change-planes-in-an-american-airport?lq=1 http://canada.usembassy.gov/visas/information-for-canadians/passing-through-the-us-between-canada-and-a-third-country.html

Comment: @MarkMayo That the US does not have international transit areas is _so_ commonly known that attempting to source it would be kind of ridiculous.