# International connection at US airport with US re-entry issue

Tags: air-travel, transit, customs-and-immigration

I need to get to the Caribbean from Europe but had overstayed in the US about 7 years back and am supposedly denied re-entry fr 10 years... since all reasonable flight scenarios I find involved going through a US Airport (like Miami), am I correct that I cannot connect from an international inbound to an international outbound without going through US Immigration and they can thus stop me from doing the connection?  Likewise on the return?

Comment: It is not possible to skip immigration in the US.  See: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/4859/do-i-need-a-us-visa-to-change-planes-in-an-american-airport

Comment: Emirates and Caribbean Air just announced a deal. Caribbean Air already flies Gatwick to Trinidad. But maybe you don't consider that reasonable due to schedule or price?

Comment: Depending on where you want to go to and from, there are lots of flights directly from Europe to places in the Caribbean, including British Airways, Virgin, Air France, KLM...

Comment: "am supposedly denied re-entry fr 10 years" You would have needed to had at least 1 year of "unlawful presence" to get a 10-year ban.

Answer (score 0):

You wouldn't even make it onto the plane.  The airline won't let you check in without a valid ESTA or visa, and you won't get an ESTA or visa with your 10 year bar (assuming you are honest with the questions, which you should be unless you want to be in an even bigger world of hurt)