# Technical stop USA transit visa

Tags: visas, usa, transit, croatian-citizens

I´m travelling to New Zealand from Croatia and my route mentions technical stop in Los Angeles.
Do I need transit visa for U.S.A.?

Comment: We'll need your nationality to tell you if you need a visa for quality for visa-free entry.

Comment: I am Croatian citizen.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Do I need a US visa to change planes in an American airport?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/4859/do-i-need-a-us-visa-to-change-planes-in-an-american-airport)

Comment: @user102008 It's a tech stop though, not a layover. Does your ticket mention a change of planes ?

Comment: I thought i don't need transit visa because my ticket doesn't mention change of planes. Then I've called American Embassy in Croatia and they told me I must have it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suppose you're flying Air New Zealand's London-LAX-Auckland flight. Then their site says you do need a visa or ESTA:

http://www.airnewzealand.co.nz/connecting-at-los-angeles

> **Changes to LAX transit process for customers travelling between
>   Auckland and London Heathrow on NZ1 and NZ2**
>
> On arrival at LAX, transit customers continuing on the same aircraft
>   to Auckland (NZ 1) or London Heathrow (NZ 2) will be directed by
>   ground staff down to US Customs and Border Protection processing.
>   Following, passengers will then be directed to a designated transit
>   location for security screening by the Transportation Security
>   Administration (TSA). Once screened, passengers will be directed back
>   into the central terminal area where they will have complete access to
>   the departure area, including the 150,000 square feet of retail and
>   dining space in TBIT’s Great Hall. For those eligible (Business
>   Premier, Star Alliance Gold & other eligible customers), transiting
>   passengers will also have access to the Star Alliance Lounge.
>   Passengers must retain their boarding passes at all times. There is no
>   requirement to complete any arrival forms and checked baggage will
>   remain onboard during transit time. **Customers are still required to
>   meet all entry requirements including having a current visa or ESTA
>   where applicable.**

Comment: Yes I contacted American embassy in Croatia and they told me I need visa.. Thanks anyway.