# From UK to Chile through Atlanta

Tags: visas, esta, us-visa-waiver-program, bulgarian-citizens

I know that maybe this question has been asked many times, but most likely from different nationalities. 
I did read quite a lot of questions and unfortunately I didn't see anyone with my nationality.
I'm a Bulgarian passport holder( BULGARIA IS NOT IN THE VISA WAIVER PROGRAM) and I will travel from London(Heathrow) to Chile(Santiago) through Atlanta with layover for more than 5 hours. 
DO I NEED ESTA OR ANY KIND OF VISA?
I'm 99% sure that ESTA is only required for passport holders under the VISA WAIVER PROGRAM, but wanted to ask just in case. 
I already asked the airline I'm flying with, but still waiting for respond and I'm kind of nervous about it...so would like to know as soon as possible. If anyone has relevant information will be highly appreciated. 
Thanks,
Zamtelligent

Comment: As the [canonical answer](http://travel.stackexchange.com/a/4991/1480) explains, the answer is *yes*. It is impossible to transit the United States without being admitted into the United States. Therefore, if your country is not included in the VWP, you must apply for a [transit visa](http://travel.state.gov/content/visas/en/other/transit.html) at a minimum. Note also that the airline is not responsible for your documentation, only you are.

Answer (score 1):

You are right that ESTA is only for those entering under the Visa Waiver Program. Since Bulgaria is not part of the Visa Waiver Program, you will need a visa to transit in the US (unless you happen to have another citizenship or documents you're not telling us about). You can apply for a [transit visa](http://travel.state.gov/content/visas/en/other/transit.html) for this purpose.

If you are applying for a visa in Bulgaria, here is [the local application information](http://bulgaria.usembassy.gov/niv.html) from the US Embassy in Sofia.

As an American, I'll say sorry. I know it's inconvenient and annoying.