# Do I need an ESTA for a connecting flight to Mexico?

Tags: usa, transit, esta, eu

I'm flying to Mexico and I have a connecting flight over Philadelphia (e.g. Munich -> Philadelphia -> Cancun).

My stop in USA is about 4 hours, and I am not planning to leave the airport during that time.

Do I need an ESTA or visa?

Comment: https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/4859/4171