# Indian traveling India to Ecuador via UK and US; do I need transit visas?

Tags: visas, usa, uk, customs-and-immigration, transit-visas

I am traveling from India to Ecuador via London Heathrow on November 28. I will be at LHR on 28th at 6:20 am and departing at 10:25 am. I'm an Indian national and go to Ecuador on arrival visa and my second layover in Miami USA there is only 1 hour and 55 minute stay. Do I need a transit visa to stay airside?

Comment: Welcome to TSE. Please see *[Is there a way to find out if I need a transit visa for a layover in the UK?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/34106/is-there-a-way-to-find-out-if-i-need-a-transit-visa-for-a-layover-in-the-uk)* and *[Do I need a US visa to transit (or layover) through an American airport?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/4859/)* which should answer your questions.

Answer (score 0):

There are no transit corridors at US airports (i.e. you cannot stay airside), meaning you'll need a transit visa for the US (type C1).

As for the UK, as stated on [the GOV.UK website](https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa/y/india/transit/somewhere_else/no), because you hold valid a US visa, you do **not** need a visa for transiting the UK.

So you need one visa only: a C1 visa for the US