# Does a non-US resident need a visa for an international connection through USA?

Tags: visas, usa, customs-and-immigration, transit-visas, venezuelan-citizens

I have purchased a ticket a friend to come and visit me in Australia.

She is a Venezuelan passport holder, but lives in Panama. We already sorted her Australian tourist visa.

However, there are concerns raised that she needs a DS160 to make that connecting flight through the USA.

The flight:

- Panama -> IAH (George Bush Intercontinental Airport)
- IAH -> Sydney

I called United, and they said their system doesn't show any requirements are needed.

I also tried calling immigration numbers, airport numbers, just automated voice message hell.

However, the internet says any flight that goes THROUGH the USA, is counted as a visit there, and therefore you need a visa.

Does she need some visa for this or not?

Comment: Duplicate of [Do I need a US visa to transit (or layover) through an American airport?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/4859/do-i-need-a-us-visa-to-transit-or-layover-through-an-american-airport)

Comment: She will absolutely need a US visa

Comment: Is the DS160 the correct VISA to apply for?

Comment: DS-160 is not a visa, it's the form you use as a part of the visa application.  She will need either a Transit (C) or Visitor visa (B-2)