# Unvaccinated travel from Canada to Mexico with a stop in the US?

Tags: stopovers

Mexico doesn't require vaccination but the US does. Even though I wouldn't be leaving the airport at the US stop it looks like I wouldn't be allowed on the plane though.  Would you agree?  Probably segregating people at a stop would be a logistical nightmare for airport staff.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Do I need a US visa to transit (or layover) through an American airport?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/4859/do-i-need-a-us-visa-to-transit-or-layover-through-an-american-airport)

Comment: Whilst not an exact duplicate of the above (one talks about visas, one about vaccination), the answer, and the reasoning is the same - when in transit in the US you are treated as an arriving passenger in every way, which includes vaccination requirements.

Answer (score 3):

> Probably segregating people at a stop would be a logistical nightmare for airport staff.

That's called "transit" and that is unfortunately a concept the US and Canada don't have.

For the most part connecting in the US has the same requirements as entering the US. There may be exceptions but this depends a lot on your specific details and may take considerable effort to research and track: Covid related rules do change fast. It would be safest to assume that have to meet the same requirements as for entry into the US.

Comment: Especially for most Canadian-originated flights to the U.S., you legally "enter" (or rather get admitted into) the U.S. at the Canadian airport already after the preclearance area.

Comment: Only if they give you a boarding pass first :-)

Comment: @xngtng although the passengers are still legally in Canada as per https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_border_preclearance#Legal_restrictions.