# What visa procedures/rules apply in Australia for a Swede 2013?

Tags: visas, australia, eu-citizens, swedish-citizens

I am 35 years old going to Australia, not planning to work.

I've understood there are (at least) two different time spans for visas, < 3 months and > 3 months.

**What is required to get a visa for 3-6 months, and how long time does it take?**

Comment: You have 2 questions, probably better to split. Regarding your first question, there is an answer giving some directions: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/1930/does-an-eu-citizen-need-a-visa-to-visit-australia-for-holidays/4511#4511

Comment: Australia changed their visas 2013, hence this question. Your link and it's answers is too old.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an handy wizard to figure out what [visa you will need](http://www.immi.gov.au/visawizard/) to apply for depending on you duration of stay.

And on the same site there is a [page describing standard processing time](http://www.immi.gov.au/about/charters/client-services-charter/standards/2.1.htm) for various visas, which you can take a look at.